# Applying Tablecellrenderer to column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Trying to apply `tablecellrenderer` to column.I need to have three different icons, for folders, zip\rar files, and others.

How can i set up them?.

If clause `(if f.isDirectory())` doesn't work at all.

```
public class FirstCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                hasFocus, row, column);
        File f = (File) value;
        ImageIcon folderIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/folder.png"));
        ImageIcon archiveIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/archive.png"));

        if (!isSelected) {
            label.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.LIGHT_GRAY : Color.WHITE);
        }

        label.setIcon(f.isDirectory() ? folderIcon : archiveIcon);
        label.setText(f.getName());

        return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it `folderIcon` that is visible all the time?

Comment: See also [`FileBrowser`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446).

Answer (score 1):

There could be any number of reasons why you're not getting the results you expect, but you've provided such little information for us to diagnose the problem with that it's all speculation.

**You might have-** Forgotten to register the renderer with the table, or registered it with the wrong type or column
**You might have-** Not put the images in the right location
**You might have-** No directories in your file listing.

The following is a simple example that demonstrates that the core concept of your renderer is working, there must be something else missing...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable100();
    }

    public TestTable100() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
                model.addColumn("Files");
                for (File file : new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).listFiles()) {
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{file});
                }

                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new FirstCellRenderer());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class FirstCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                            value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            File f = (File) value;
//            ImageIcon folderIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
//                            "/images/folder.png"));
//            ImageIcon archiveIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
//                            "/images/archive.png"));

            if (!isSelected) {
                label.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.LIGHT_GRAY : Color.WHITE);
            }

//            label.setIcon(f.isDirectory() ? folderIcon : archiveIcon);
            String prefix = f.isDirectory() ? "[d]" : "[f]";
            label.setText(prefix + " " + f.getName());

            return label;
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated to display Zip files differently**

[image: Table]

Beware that the `File` API doesn't handle some "special" files well, things like symbolic links or Windows equivalent (I'm look at you My Music)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable100();
    }

    public TestTable100() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
                model.addColumn("Files");
                for (File file : new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).listFiles()) {
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{file});
                }

                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new FirstCellRenderer());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class FirstCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        protected static ImageIcon FOLDER_ICON;
        protected static ImageIcon FILE_ICON;
        protected static ImageIcon ZIP_FILE_ICON;

        static {
            try {
                FOLDER_ICON = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(FirstCellRenderer.class.getResource("/Folder.png")));
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                FOLDER_ICON = null;
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                FILE_ICON = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(FirstCellRenderer.class.getResource("/File.png")));
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                FILE_ICON = null;
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ZIP_FILE_ICON = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(FirstCellRenderer.class.getResource("/ZipFile.png")));
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                ZIP_FILE_ICON = null;
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            File f = (File) value;
            setIcon(null);
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                setIcon(FOLDER_ICON);
            } else {
                String name = f.getName();
                if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip")) {
                    setIcon(ZIP_FILE_ICON);
                } else {
                    setIcon(FILE_ICON);
                }
            }
            setText(f.getName());

            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the point was, how can i set 3 images instead of two? In my folder I have directories, files and zip files, I need to set up for them diferent icons.

Comment: and don't, you couldn't to provide any FileIO (doesn't matter if is in embeded resources) inside XxxRenderer, there is crazy number of events that are called from every mouse, key and internal methods

Comment: @Cupuycblack I still don't see the problem, apart from your example doesn't even make an attempt to do what you've asked...

Answer (score 0):

Try these ones

```
label.setIcon(f.getParent()==null ? folderIcon : archiveIcon);
//label.setIcon(f.getParentFile()==null ? folderIcon : archiveIcon);
```

in place of below line

```
label.setIcon(f.isDirectory() ? folderIcon : archiveIcon);
```